# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value using AVAudio

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, swift, avfoundation

I've got two projects, using the same bit of code, but the following line:

```
player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: fileLocation), error: &error)
```

is returning this error in only one of the projects:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil unwrapping an Optional value
```

The other project runs with no error.

I am trying to play a sound.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var fileLocation =  NSString(string: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("halloweenmp3", ofType: "mp3")!)

        var error: NSError? = nil

        player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: fileLocation), error: &error)

        player.play()


}
```

In both projects the same mp3 file has been added to the project but one project will play the sound while the other returns the error.

The project that is giving me the error does have other code in it, but the error only seems to relate to the line mentioned above so I don't see how another bit of code in the project could be causing it.

I've tried duplicating the error-prone project and get the same result. I've created new projects and use the same bit of code used above and had it work. I'm not sure if the project is corrupted somehow or another bit of code in the project is causing the error even though it's not being referred to in the debugger.

I can preview the mp3 file from the file navigator in xCode so it is working and is there.

Comment: You should examine the file URL string and make sure it's not `nil`. Then examine the `NSURL` and make sure that's not `nil`. Whenever you get the "unexpected found `nil`" error, you simply have to go through each object and figure out which one was `nil`. It could be file missing from bundle. It could be typo or capitalization error.

Comment: @Rob is spot on. When you're getting an error from a line of code that combines several operations, it can help to split them out for tracking down the issue.

Comment: I finally just decided to start a new project, rewrite the code and it worked. None of my objects were `nil` so I don't know what the issue was. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Changing `NSURL(String:)` to `NSURL(fileURLWithPath:)` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You may do this:

1. In your Project View, click your project name
2. Select your target and Select "Build Phases" tab
3. Drag your mp3 file into your "Copy Bundle 
   Resources" section

Comment: Oh my god, dude, I was almost thinking it's a kind of magic, but now it seems so stupid. Why Xcode won't include mp3 sources into compiled bundle automatically?